# run successfully on development computer. But fail to load z3.dll when I run the packaged winform application on other computer

Tags: c#, dll, z3

I have developed an win-form application using Z3 api for C#. The application can run successfully  on the computer which I used to develop. But after I build a setup project with the "SETUP AND DEPLOYMENT" function in VISUAL STUDIO 2010. The packaged application cannot run successfully on computers other than the development computer. Error message: failed to load z3.dll when running.  What should I do to solve the problem？

Answer (score 3):

`z3.dll` is unmanaged dll which is used by `Microsoft.Z3.dll`. Sadly, you cannot reference it by `Reference` dialog in Visual Studio.

I guess `z3.dll` is missing in the installation folder where `Microsoft.Z3.dll` is present.

I suggest that you run the application (including `z3.dll` and `Microsoft.Z3.dll` in the same folder) on a new machine, and try to pack all necessary bits to an installation package when they run fine.

Comment: I have copied the Z3.dll to the set up folder and the windows/system32 folder, but the application cannot run successfully yet.

Comment: Can you verify that `z3.dll` and `Microsoft.Z3.dll` are present in the setup folder? I would try to run the application with all necessary dlls in another machine before going for Setup and Deployment.

Comment: After I imported all the .dll files in Z3-4.0 bin folder, the application can run successfully. But it can only run no Windows7. On Windows XP, the application cannot run successfully